# Retrain Stanford coreNLP Lemmatizer

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, javadoc, lemmatization

I am trying to work out how the lemmatizer could support the particular use case of identifying e.g. certain regional variants in a corpus. The two possible approaches that I could follow could be:

- amend the existing dictionary to use my own material, or
- retrain the lemmatizer

I am wondering if you can point me to documentation that I can follow for either approach. I am aware that the Lemma module works in this way:

```
PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
    "annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma",
    "ssplit.isOneSentence", "true",
    "tokenize.language", "en"));
```

Apart from `CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation`, I wasn't able to track something for what I would like to do. I’d appreciate any help you can provide.

Many thanks